# Iterator is fail-fast and Enumeration is not. Are there additional differences between the two other than the points given by Javadoc?

Tags: java

According to Javadoc,

> New implementations should consider using Iterator in preference to Enumeration

If newer implementations should consider using Iterator, why is Enumeration not deprecated?

Iterator is fail-fast and Enumeration is not. Are there additional differences between the two other than the points given by Javadoc?

Thanks

Comment: From the Javadoc: "Iterator adds an optional remove operation, and has shorter method names."

Comment: Java is deprecated and people still use it.

Comment: So is the C89/C90 standard, but plenty of people still use that and C99 isn't even fully implemented in all compilers. (Not to mention C99 is technically deprecated now as well, what with the new C11 standard...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many things in Java ought to be deprecated but can't because of the vast amount of legacy code. Enumeration is one, Vector, HashTable, Dictionary, Properties are others..

Comment: This was my interview question. I thought the same reason of legacy code but didn't  tell as I thought more logical reason behind that ;-)

Comment: From my experience, indication of deprecation normally doesn't prevent use, it just means "this still technically works, but try not to use it from now on". It doesn't mean it _will_ be removed, but it means it might be removed at a later date or there is a better way of doing things, so don't rely on it anymore if possible. And Java even has the [@Deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) annotation for that sort of stuff, which results in a warning when the code is used.

Comment: Deprecation has one serious aspect to it: it marks code that is not supported or maintained anymore and is basically just still hanging around.

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/what-is-difference-between-enumeration.html) describes the differences between Enumerations and Iterators. Basically though, the main differences seem to be that Iterators have a remove method which enumerations do not, and Iterators throw a ConcurrentModificationException if another thread is attempting to modify a collection that is being iterated over, which enumerations do not do.

Comment: It's not guaranteed that a `ConcurrentModificationException` will be thrown in all cases, though. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html Also, some/most/all of the classes in `java.util.concurrent` won't throw that exception at all. (See paragraph 2 of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html.)

Comment: No it isnt guaranteed to be thrown, I was just saying what the differences between the two are.

Answer (score 1):

For more differences:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html

> Iterator adds an optional remove operation, and has shorter method names.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator is slower than Enumeration.
Iterator can traverse legacy and non-legacy elements but Enumeration can traverse only legacy elements
Iterator is fail-fast but not fail fast.